No bean of type [io.micronaut.jdbc.DataSourceResolver] exists
I updated micronaut from 3.7.* to 4.0.0 and since then application is failing to start with the below error:
Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.jdbc.DataSourceResolver] exists. 
Path Taken: DatasourceFactory.dataSource(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration) --> new RepairingDataSourceMigrationRunner(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,[DataSourceResolver dataSourceResolver])
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1982)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:294)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3348)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3692)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:342)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:202)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:74)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [dataSourceResolver] of class

I have this included n my gradle already:
implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc")

I also have datasources listed in the application.yaml. I'm not getting what I'm missing here. Can someone please help on this?

To be able to reproduce your issue, we'll need at least the complete build.gradle / build.gradle.kts and application.yml

It seems DataSourceResolver is deprecated in micronaut's updated release, I removed the same and adding some default configs instead. That resolved

I removed injecting DataSourceResolver as I found it deprecated in micronaut's updated release and that has fixed the issue.
